# What is the relationship between ems and pixels?

Tags: html, css, font-size

What is the value of an em in terms of pixels?

10em = ?px ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's no specific relationship between em and px. It's computed based on the width of the "m" character for each font-face.

Comment: In traditional typography it is. In CSS, however, it is the font height.

Comment: Quentin is correct.  The answer is wrong. In CSS 1em should equal whatever the current fontsize is.  If you don't believe me [look at the following](http://jsfiddle.net/YXdpC/).

Answer (score 6):

While as others have said, there is no set ratio - as it varies from font to font - it is possible to calculate this for a **particular** font face/size combination by using DHTML.

Simply create a div with

```
style="width: 1em; visibility:hidden"
```

and append it to the place in the document you are interested about.

You can then find out its width by checking the div's `clientWidth` property

Comment: This is the correct way to do it. I typically create an element on the page: `<div id="em"></div>` and the following css: `#em {width:1em; height:1em; overflow:hidden; visibility:hidden;}` which I can than target with regular JavaScript on page load to define the value of an 'em' unit in relation to pxs.

Comment: Another important comment about this method, em values are relative. So I always leave the `<body>` element as 1em and I always place my html from above directly below this. If you were to set it higher or lower, it would modify the values accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on the font and the platform you're rendering on.  There is no universal ratio.

Answer (score 0):

It's about 160px, if 1em is 16px and 10em = 1000%. It's just an approximation, which will depend on font, browser and OS.

Comment: first of all it doesn't make sense, how are you comparing to relative %'s?

Comment: @CrazyJugglerDrummer, Ems are relative too, 1em = 100% obviously. Pixels and points are depend on font, browser and OS.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a standard sized text font of 11 or 12px then a general rule of thumb is 1em is going to be about that big in pixels, so 11 or 12 pixels.

Comment: A CSS em is "The size of the font", so that isn't so much a general rule of thumb and as absolute rule.

Answer (score 0):

By default `1em` is 16px (`font-size:100%;`), so 16px x 10em = 160px

You can change the size of an `em` by changing the percent of the `font-size` in the body, for example if you want to change the size of an `em` to 10px, this would be your CSS:

```
body {
font-size:62.5%;
}
```

16px x 62.5% = 10px

Comment: The default is whatever the user has their font size set to. This is often 16px, but not always.